# remote debugging wcf service using visual studio 2010

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am trying to debug remotely my wcf services using visual studio 2010, remote machine  win srv 2003 with IIS 6
 I keep on receiving the following error

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

The following module was built either with optimizations enabled or without debug information:

c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\491f1a5c\3c7386d6\assembly\dl3\20ac69eb\a4e6ceed_8c24cc01\xxxxxx.Interfaces.dll

### To debug this module, change its project build configuration to Debug mode. To suppress this message, disable the 'Warn if no user code on launch' debugger option.

### OK

my build is in debug mode, I have deleted the temp file and redeploy, restart visual studio, but without any chance. can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue as well.  I have found that stopping the service before you re-deploy the WCF service fixes the issue.  I think part of the problem is that something is accessing the WCF which causes the DLL to stay in memory although I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your web.config and see if the following is there:

```
<configuration>

...
  <system.web>
    ...  
    <compilation debug="true" />
    ...
  </system.web>

...
</configuration>
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove that when you deploy to production.

Comment: Typically people trying to get points by helping you are pissing in the wind...  Unless someone ran into this and documented it, or in my case... I just ran into it.  I'm using vs 2010 sp1 , and tried several things,  I was going to delete the dll from my path error C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2c0d3658\caacfa0a\assembly\dl3\53e39126\e888ca9f_7252cc01 INSTEAD I SHUTDOWN visual studio and IIS EXPRESS I stopped .... Then I re-opened the project and things were fine.  I thought I have a 10-25% chance of it fixing itself... but I fixed itself fine.